# attempting to make uneditable field editable in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I seem to be hitting a roadblock when attempting to make a field editable in the Purchase Order screen.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM.Extensions;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using SOOrder = PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder;
using SOLine = PX.Objects.SO.SOLine;
using PX.Data.DependencyInjection;
using PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes;
using PX.LicensePolicy;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Objects.AP.MigrationMode;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Objects.Common.Bql;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.CostAccrual;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Data.WorkflowAPI;
using PX.Objects.Common.Scopes;
using PX.Objects.IN.Services;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.MultiCurrency;
using PX.Data.Description;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.PO;

namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
  public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

  protected static void POOrderEntry_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseHandler)
  {
  baseHandler?.Invoke(cache, e);
var row = (POOrderEntry)e.Row;
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POOrder.SOOrderNbr.>(cache, row, true);
}
    #endregion
  }
}
```

The error message i got was while validating the customisation project.
error message below:

```
\App_RuntimeCode\POOrderEntry.cs(50): error CS1001: Identifier expected
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Aleks

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an extra dot in line 50, after SOOrderNbr.
2. SOOrderNbr is must be sOOrderNbr, you need to use the classname here.

   PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POOrder.sOOrderNbr>(cache, row, true);

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately after publishing the customisation project this broke the Purchase Orders page.

Comment: How does it broke the PO screen?

Answer (score 0):

couple of points:

1. Methods in DAC Extension shouldn't be static.
   Instead of

   ```
   protected static void POOrderEntry_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseHandler)
   {
   ```

you should use

```
protected virtual void POOrderEntry_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseHandler)
   {
```

And in your code, you should use lowercase:
instead of

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POOrder.SOOrderNbr.>(cache, row, true);
```

you can use:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POOrder.sOOrderNbr>(cache, doc, false);
```

In such case you'll be able to avoid typos and other errors.